# Floating DIV with undefined number of DIVs next to it

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a typical float but not have text surrounding it but `<div>` which should horizontally fill but not overlap with the float.

Imagine this HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="avatar">
    :)
    </div>
    <div class="line">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
    <div class="line">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy.</div>
    <div class="line">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy.</div>
</div>
```

I do not now how many of the lines will be next to the avatar and which is the first one which is below the avatar - so given some of them width *A* and some of them width *B* does not work.

This [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ZoolWay/gshg8yfb/) shows an example. The `<div>` elements overlap with the avatar.

Using `float` I cannot get the `<div>` elements to stretch to the float. [Here is a float example](https://jsfiddle.net/ZoolWay/bue9c830/1/) where only the first `<div>` is positioned next to the float and the lines do not fill up horizontal space.

Any idea how I can achieve this type of layout?

[image: layout example]

Remember I do not know the exact size of the orange area and how many blues fit left to it (ideally the layout would be responsive). Also the blue ones should be as wide as possible as seen in the draft above.

Comment: is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/h633ofcj/) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this type of layout.  https://jsfiddle.net/2L7e8b4n/

**HTML**

```
 <div id="main">
   <div id="avatar">
     :)
   </div>
   <div class="line">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
   <div class="line">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing 
     elitr, sed diam nonumy.</div>
   <div class="line">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing 
     elitr, sed diam nonumy.</div>
   <div class="line">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing 
     elitr, sed diam nonumy.</div>
   <div class="line">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing 
     elitr, sed diam nonumy.</div>
   <div class="line">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing 
     elitr, sed diam nonumy.</div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 div#main {
   border: 1px solid black;
   width: 220px;
   height: 220px;
   position: relative;
   }

 div#avatar {
   width: 40px;
   height: 49px;
   border: 1px orange  dotted;
   float:right;
   }

 div.line {
   font-size: 8px;
   min-height: 12px;
   border-bottom: 1px silver solid;
   overflow: hidden;
   }
```

Comment: Hm, looks like `overflow: hidden` is the key. The text still wraps but the lines to no longer overlay the float.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about the normal float behaviour, you are describing a float element but not actually using one! :D

Here is what you are after:

```
div#avatar {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 1px orange dotted;
  float:right;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gshg8yfb/2/

Comment: In your fiddle the bottom border of the line `<div>` still overlays with the float at the top right. But the answer from nish seems to work, it added `overflow: hidden`

Comment: This was not mentioned as a prerequisite anywhere, but, hm, ok. However, keep in mind that if the 3rd li content is larger, then nish's solution creates other kinds of artifacts. Anyway, take your pick! :D